# Storing revisions in SQL Server (simply much like TFS)

Tags: sql-server, database-design, architecture, version-control

So, what I've got so far:

**Table: ChangeSets**

Columns: Id | Comment | Committer

**Table: Customers**

Columns: Id | Name

**Table: CustomerChangeSets**

Columns: Id | CustomerId (FK) | ChangeSetId (FK)

So now I can have multiple customer changes in one changeset (again very much like TFS). Every changeset in a customer object now results in a new customer object being created (and a new Id assigned due to an identity column).

My problem now is, that I don't know how to represent the mapping from and to my customers. I've got several tables that reference to `Customers.Id`, but that'd mean I would have a reference to an old version of a customer (the initial one, without any changes).

What's the best way?

- Don't create a new customer on each checkin? But how would I get my
  required logic then?
- Update all the foreign keys to my new `Customer.Id`? That'd take
  quite a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously when you check in a changeset, you know who the customer is (or was) according to what you describe about your process.  Even TFS requires *something* to be the same, so that it can maintain history.

In any case, in multiple versions of the same object, what is constant?

Is the "Name" constant? (Probably not.) If the Customers table were that simple I do not see what you are tracking other than a name change.  But likely the table is much more complex.

But as long as you know this is the same Customer, you should carry a *constant value* in the new Customer rows. Something like:

```
 Table: Customers
 Columns: Id | CustomerNumber| Name
```

That way "Id" is just a row surrogate key, but CustomerNumber would be assigned once and would be a datum included in the versions of the data you are tracking.

I suppose that the CustomerNumber could be the first Id assigned to this Customer, but I would suggest an independent numbering scheme, perhaps check-digited for a degree of protection from entry errors, should that ever be needed publicly.

Comment: So, then I'd have like two identity columns, one auto-incrementing for each version and the other one constant throughout a single customer? And this constant value is going to be used as a reference then?

Comment: The second value would not use the IDENTITY property, since you want to have a constant value.  As I mentioned, you could choose the first IDENTITY value for that customer as the constant, or you could generate some other key that is in a different number range.  Up to you, but you do NEED a constant for reasonable processing time.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

**Table: Customers**

Columns: CustomerId

**Table: ChangeSets**

Columns: ChangeSetId | Comment | Committer

**Table: CustomerVersions**

Columns: CustomerId | ChangeSetId | AllOtherCustomerData

We typically need two kinds of FK references, both a more permanent one to Customers (this is the employee's laptop/iPhone etc) and a more volatile one to CustomerVersions (this is the employee's current position, location, etc.)